# Are multiple entry points for Azure Logic Apps possible or should I be looking at Azure Functions?

Tags: .net, azure, salesforce, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

I've got an issue currently that I'm trying to sync some of our Salesforce data to an external CRM. Now originally I found that through Azure functions it would be so easy to listen to any record being modified or created and push that data somewhere (In this case straight to a Topic in Azure). I love the functionality and it works wonderfully but I can't seem to figure out if there is a way to have multiple entry points in a Logic App. I'm assuming the answer is no since they aren't really designed for that.

If that is the case is there some already built out easy way with Azure functions to listen to records being modified/created in Salesforce?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by multiple entry points but the OOB Salesforce connector has triggers for "When record is created" and "When a record is modified"

Comment: Yes so I understand I can listen to those triggers I have been using them but I need to listen to an account being created, and an account being modified, and an asset being created, and an asset being modified. I don't want to have to create 4 logic apps to listen to these 4 triggers.